# Flask route not found

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am building a catalog app using flask and sqlalchemy but one of my routes is giving a 404 and I'm not sure why. Here is the code for the route and function:

```
@app.route('/Category/<string:category_name>/Item/new', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def newItem(category_name):
    user = getUser()
    if user is None:
        return redirect('/login')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        newItem = Category(name=request.form['name'],
        description=request.form['description'], creator=session['username'],
        category_id=db.query(Category.id).filter_by(category_name=category_name).all())
        db.add(newItem)
        db.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('showCategory(category_name)'))
    else:
        return render_template('newItem.html', categories=categories)
```

The newItem.html template does exist in the template folder, and using another route I have for viewing an item: `@app.route('/Category/<string:category_name>/Item/<string:item_name>` works so category_name is being defined. The url I'm going to is `https://localhost:5000/Category/Sports/Item/new` and Sports is a category in the database, I cannot figure out why I'm getting the 404

Traceback (shows trying to enter showItem route not newItem route):[image]

Comment: Could you show the full stacktrace? Does the error happen when you try to redirect in this line of code - `return redirect(url_for('showCategory(category_name)'))`?

Comment: Could you provide a link to your Git repo?

Comment: @AamirKhan Why would you need link to his repo?

Comment: @Nurzhan Added the traceback, it tries to use the route for viewing an item named "new" instead of going into the route I defined. Aamir, It's a local git repo not online.

Comment: @WillScott Sqlalchemy is complaining that it cannot find a particular record. Fix that and see if it works.

Comment: @Nurzhan It's complaining it can't find a record because thats not the intended route the line its complaining about is in showItem() not newItem() so it should be irrelevant to the newItem function, also the line its complaining about works when I go to the proper route

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your URL rules are hitting the wrong function...

`@app.route('/Category/<string:category_name>/Item/<string:item_name>`
happens to match
`https://localhost:5000/Category/Sports/Item/new`

You need to add an extra segment to the first one like
`@app.route('/Category/<string:category_name>/Item/existing/<string:item_name>`

Comment: Also, maybe it's the matter of order (when registering views).

Comment: While you may be able to work around it by changing the order, it is a much better idea to make sure that your routes are completely unambiguous, if a string can match two of them, change one.

Comment: This is a solution but I want the URL to be as simple as possible, @dizpers it is ordered correctly. I did a bunch of messing around and I'm not sure what exactly fixed it but its working now so I'll accept this answer since it is a solution.

Comment: @PaulBecotte agree :)

Comment: you could use an id instead of name, giving you `<int:item_id>` for the GET route while still being unambiguous

Answer (score 0):

You're getting [sqlalchemy.orm.exc.NoResultFound](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/exceptions.html#sqlalchemy.orm.exc.NoResultFound) exception. It means that view function was called successfully, but now data could be found.

Comment: That view function works fine when I go to the route for that function, its throwing the exception because it's trying to run showItem() when the route should be running newItem()

Comment: So, just to confirm. You're calling `GET https://localhost:5000/Category/Sports/Item/new` (for `newItem` view) and getting traceback with `showItem` view)?